# Вывод записей на странице

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, запись

Есть несколько записей заданных в Wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некоторые из них присутствуют на странице `blog.php`. Как осуществить вывод всех записей, присутствующих на `blog.php`, если `blog.php` является **шаблоном** страницы (см. https://wp-kama.ru/id_5177/3-sposoba-sozdat-shablon-stranitsyi.html) ?

Comment: Используйте [WP_Query](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query) или [get_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts). Почему было просто это не загуглить? [вывод записей WordPress](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9+wordpress)

Comment: @Simon 1. а как осуществить проверку **принадлежности** записи странице? 2. И как задать в админке вордпресса **принадлежность** записи странице? Я искал, но не нашел - ткните пожалуйста. Напишите в ответе - я проголосую.

Comment: Запись не принадлежит и не может принаджлежать странице напрямую, между записью и страницей нет связи по-умолчанию (как например между таксономией и записью). Ее можно реализовать либо посредством кастомного метабокса, либо использовав [ACF Relationsip](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) и его аналоги в других плагинах.

Comment: @Simon а можете описать как задать в админке вордпресса **принадлежность** странице при помощи одного из приведенных методов? За ответ я проголосую. Причем выбор метода должен позволить осуществить проверку **принадлежности** записи странице с помощью WP_Query или get_posts.

Comment: Пример с ACF Relationship есть в документации, Вы создаете группу полей (используя поле Relationship), присваиваете ее странице нужной Вам, выбираете уже редактируя страницу нужные записи и в примерах в доках описано как их вывести. Но если нужно через WP_Query, можете в настройках указать чтобы Вам возвразало только ID, массив которых Вы можете подставить в [post__in](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query)

Comment: @Simon Для того же вывода через WP_Query, можете в настройках указать чтобы Вам возвразало только ID, массив которых Вы можете подставить в post__in - можете подробнее описать как осуществить проверку **принадлежности** записи странице с помощью WP_Query? (пишите в ответе) И ссылку на пример из документации ACF Relationship киньте.

Comment: Там не нужна никакая проверка. Когда Вы на странице получаете занчение поля при помощи [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) функции она возвращает значения которые хранятся в мета этой страницы с ключем данного поля. Мне неудобно писать в ответе, так как разжовывание всего этого целиком тянет на статью с скринами и тому подобным.

Comment: @Simon Я объясню как я понимаю: Есть множество всех записей в wordpress (Записи ->Все записи). На странице blog.php отображается только часть из этих записей. Как на blog.php вывести только те записи, которые должны отображаться на ней (а не все)?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134234/discussion-between-simon-and-wfamilyweb).